# Schema project, for building proto file stubs, only updates one <Protobuf target

Tags: c#, msbuild, protocol-buffers, grpc

My setup is as follows:

3 .NET Framework libraries all using gRPC and protobuf.

**Schema**: Contains all proto files

**Server**: Should receive the generated C# Server stubs

**Client**: Should receive the generated C# Client stubs

Building of the proto files is taken from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md) in my case i added as an item group to my schema csproj:

```
<Protobuf Include="**\*.proto" OutputDir="..\Client\Generated\" CompileOutputs="false" GrpcServices="Client" />
<Protobuf Update="**\*.proto" OutputDir="..\Server\Generated\" CompileOutputs="false" GrpcServices="Server" />
```

The first time this worked fine, all expected files were written. But then i added a new property to a message in one of my proto files, rebuild the schema project. And only the Server project received the updated content, the client project was still having an old reference.

If i write `Include="**...` in both lines, i get duplicates of all proto files in the Solution Explorer, as expected and rebuilding produces a bunch of duplicated code errors, but turning it back to `Include` and `Update` suddenly all files are up to date.

So my question: Is the approach in itself flawed? Am i missing something? Is there a better way to do what i want?

And a bonus question: Can automatically add the generated C# files to the target projects with this approach?

Comment: Your setup is a bit odd. You should either generate all the code (both server and client) and have a shared "Schema" project that other projects in the solution depend on OR you should have two separate Client and Server projects that each generate what they need (and no project in your solution should ever depend on both).  It seems that you're trying to do something in-between and I don't think that's supported (I have a hard time imagining where the setup you're describing would be useful).

Comment: Its not a particular usecase i want to enforce. I just wanted to have a single place for my proto files, be able to build that and have a way to produce the output for 2 different projects (Client & Server). The shared Schema project would still mean that the Client contains the server stubs which i consider bad practice. Your second idea is more sound, by having an external folder with the proto file, and both projects reference that.